# How to use a C++ Library in flutter using Dart::FFI?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use [dLib](http://dlib.net/) C++ Library in flutter to implement Face Recognition. I am new to C++ and dart documentation is not very helpful for my case. Has anyone implemented something like this before. Can you please guide me through it

Comment: Search "flutter week conference"

Comment: Thanks Richard. The talk was very helpful.